# select multiple joins to display using more than 3 tables

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables as follows:

1. User,  2. Article,  3. Client, 4. ClientArticle

The fields are as follows:

1. User : ID, ClientID, Name
2. Article: Article ID, Name, value
3. Client: ID, Name
4. Client Article: ID, ClientID, ArticleID

I want to have a list of Clients for `User` where `Article.value = 'y'`.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select c.Id, c.Name from Client c 
    Join ClientArticle ca on c.ID = ca.ClientID
    Join Article a on ca.ArticleID = a.ArticleId
    Where a.Value = 'Y'
```

You will need to play with the join types depend on the results you want. IE. Left Join, Inner Join etc

Answer (score 0):

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2af62/1)

And your query should be

```
Select c.* from Client c 
    Join Client_Article ca on c.id = ca.ClientID
    Join Article a on ca.ArticleID = a.Article_Id
    Where a.Value = 'Y';
```

And it shows output for above fiddle example as

```
| ID | NAME |
|----|------|
| 26 |  ccc |
```